# How can I evaluate an expression in Fortran debugger idb

Tags: debugging, fortran, intel-fortran

I am using Fortran 95 with intel debugger idb. A simple question is, can I evaluate an expression? I tried different commands but none of them seemed to wrok, as below:

```
    (idb) p glccDef(p2c)                                                    
    $10 = 0.019999993778765213                                              
    (idb) p glccDef(g2c)                                                    
    $11 = -0.070000001974403842                                             
    (idb) p glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)                                       
    Internal Error: Method not finished yet: TypeConstrainedArray::add NYI. 
    Cannot evaluate 'glccDef(p2c) + glccDef(g2c)'.                          
    (idb) p "glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)"                                     
    $12 = glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)                                         
    (idb) p $12                                                             
    $13 = "glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)"                                       
    (idb) expr glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)                                    
    expr glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)                                          
       ^                                                                    
    Unable to parse input as legal command or Fortran expression.           
    (idb) expr "glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)"                                  
    expr "glccDef(p2c)+glccDef(g2c)"                                        
       ^                                                                    
    Unable to parse input as legal command or Fortran expression.
```

Hope there are somebody still working and debugging with fortran :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IDB is deprecated and not developed any more, you should switch to [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb).
See https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/530489

To your error: "**Internal Error**: Method not finished yet" It is an internal error, you should contact Intel and ask them.